# When I save a google sheet as xlsx i don't see the images I have in sheets using =image()

Tags: google-sheets

When I save a google sheet as xlsx I don't see the images I have in sheets using =image()
The exported file does not contain the images I see on the Google sheet. I have tried to copy paste the images in google sheet as value, then export to xlsx but still don't see images in the xlsx file that was downloaded.
Can someone help, please.

Comment: @cooper thanks for edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** *(following OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62536808/when-i-save-a-google-sheet-as-xlsx-i-dont-see-the-images-i-have-in-sheets-using/62545065?noredirect=1#comment110619506_62545065))*

> Can we have any script for that

You need neither a script nor a formula for that.

You only need *"to save your images using `Insert image` from the insert menu."*

[image: how to insert an image in Google sheets]

---

**[IMAGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093333) is a Google specific function and canNOT be viewed by .xlsx**

As well as any of the Google specific functions

[image]

Your alternative is to save your images by using `Insert image` from the insert menu.

Comment: Can we have any script for that

Comment: Please see the updated answer. If still in trouble let us know.

Comment: When the image is “in cell” (not using a formula), exporting to xlsx still fails to maintain the images.

Comment: @MrShane *"When the image is “in cell”..."* Correct. You need to follow different steps. Please use a new question. Also. You need NOT downvoting an answer to attract someone's attention. Please read [vote down](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: Your steps and screenshot implies the use Insert > Image > Image in cell, which you have now admitted is incorrect. Do not flatter yourself that i mark down for attention. "Downvote answers that are incorrect or don't provide sufficient information to be useful in answering the question."

Comment: @MrShane My answer is to the OP's question: *"When I save a google sheet as xlsx I don't see the images I have in sheets using =image()"* So the answer is correct, thus accepted. Your issue is completely different. Please use a new question. As for flattery......?

Comment: @marikamitsos your answer doesnt provide suffient information. Had you said "Insert > Image > Image over cells" then it would be correct, however that needs to be discovered outside your answer.

Comment: @MrShane *"Had you said...."* Please feel free and suggest an edit. Should I find it to be correct, I'll be happy to accept.